# White Labeling oAuth login page

Tags: community, rest-api, oauth2

We have a use case that requires our customers to login on our website.  Our customer identities are stored in salesforce as part of our communities section.

On our website we redirect users to 
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize
with the appropriate parameters so that they can login.  USing the oAuth WebServer flow (I Believe)

However the page is very much branded as salesforce. This would usually make sense as salesforce is the trusted entity, however our customers really don't need to know that we use salesforce and might actually be confused when shown the login page.

How do we whitelabel the oAuth login processes so that it contains our branding?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to see this section of [Getting Started with Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_customize_login.htm) which includes instructions on how to brand your log-in page, revising your Apex CommunitiesLoginController, where to configure authentication provider options and more.